# MySQL how to link tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a to do web app using mysql. Can someone explain how I can select the todos specific for one user? How do I link the users table with the todos table? General advice would be preffered, not actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called a *foreign key relation*. It goes like this

```
users table
-----------
id (auto increment primary key)
name
address
...


todos table
-----------
id (auto increment primary key)
user_id (id from users table - this is the foreign key and relation to the user)
todo_text
...
```

If you want to select the todos of a user later then you can use a join:

```
select todos.*
from todos
inner join users on users.id = todos.user_id
where users.name = 'john'
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! But I have one more problem. How can I get 'john', for example, to be the user that is currently logged in so it inserts the task into a particular user's table? Do I need a variable?

Comment: I am not quite sure about your requirements. It would be best to ask a new question. The more info you put into that new question, the faster you get an accurate answer. It is always good to add code. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You would link them by id's

So if you have two tables (UserTable) and (ToDoTable) you would get the todos with a select like this.

```
Select * from ToDoTable where ToDoTable.user_id = 1;
```

That query is essentially saying give me everything from the todotable where the user is bob (since bob has a primary key id of 1)

The user table will have users like :

```
Name | id  
Bob    1  
John   2
```

and the TodoTable will have

```
Task           |  user_id  
Clean dishes        2   
Take out Trash      1
```

That way we link the tasks to the user table by the user_id
The User table will have a primary key (id)
and it is referenced on the todo table as a foreign key